# transfer database tables and stored procedure from sql to access

Tags: asp.net, sql, winforms, ms-access

My friend had certain requirement of desktop application for his client. And he wanted sql as backend. But now he dont want it in sql.. As his client does not have SQL server

I hav already developed application. So is it possible to transfer all table access database?

Or there can be some other solution?

Comment: You can transfer tables, but not stored procedures. If you are running on the internet, MS Access is not the best choice. Access is a good choice for a small office.

Comment: yup..it is desktop application..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to transfer tables is to right-click on a linked SQL Server table in Access 2007/10 (I am not sure about earlier versions) and choose Convert to Local Table. This will preserve your indexes. If that is not available, you can run make table queries against linked tables.

You are likely to have some problems with queries (views), but switching to Ansi-92 mode may suit. However, this must be done with care: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-avoiding-the-mixing-of-queries-created-under-different-ansi-sql-query-modes-mdb-HP003070559.aspx

In Access 2010 you have data macros that can take the place of procedures to a certain extent, and will work outside of MS Access, you also have VBA, though not outside of MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer stored procedures to Access. Suggest that he uses one of the free versions of SQL Server. (Express, etc)

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Comment: I think this is a great solution since store procedures, tables triggers and virtually everything that been done will work without changes locally. The only compelling reason I can think of to re-write any store procedures and t-sql views would be if elimination of SQL server and the hassle of installing it is a goal here. If there are just a few tiny simple store procedures, then as noted Access 2010 does support table triggers and store procedures but like Oracle, MySql, SQL server they all have their own programing system and are not compatible with each other.